# Ajax - function recived the returned value and jumps to error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a function that sends an ajax request and it needs to get the returned data as array of strings.

While debugging I can see the response and in the same time the error function runs.

My code is like this:

```
function getHazards() {
    $.ajax({
        async: true,
        url: web + "/GetHazards",
        method: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (data) {
            var res= data;
            var i;
            var arr = new Array();
            for (i = 0; res[i] != null; i++) {
                arr[i] = JSON.parse(res[i]);
            }
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
}
```

The response is ok, but the error function runs.

Comment: Check your dev console.

Comment: could you explain me more about what i need to check ?

Comment: Are you using Chrome?

Comment: Yes, i am using Chrome.

Comment: Hit F12, click console, run your code and check for errors.

Comment: What is the content of `res`? Can you give a couple of simple examples

Comment: I already checked, I can see the data that i need to use, but the error function runs

Comment: @Huangism, he said that it's going straight to `error:`. I don't think he's having a chance of seeing what's inside `res`.

Comment: @Huangism, this is an exapmle of the returned data, {"d":["3014","32.261592864990234","35.014228820800781","3013","32.342685699462891","34.910316467285156",....]

Comment: Add `data` to the error function and see what it returns.

Comment: @doutriforce it's intresting, that what i am asking, i see the response and it's exactly what i need,

Comment: Do you mean like this : error: function(data){ alert(data); } ?

Comment: Yes. You could replace `alert(data);` by `debugger;` though. Then keep the console opened (F12) and, when it stops on the breakpoint, watch what's inside `data`.

Comment: @doutriforce Works!! thank you all,

Comment: No problem, mate.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getHazards() {
    $.ajax({
        async: true,
        url: web + "/GetHazards",
        method: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        complete: function (data) { // use complete instead of error for debugging
            console.log('data', data)
        },
    });
}
```

Comment: It would be useful if you could explain what’s different.